# django admin truncate text in list_display

Tags: django, list, admin, display

Need to trunate text in admin list_display

Have the following in admin model but still shows full text.

```py
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatewords

def get_description(self, obj):
    return truncatewords(obj.description, 10)
get_description.short_description = "description"

class DieTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =['severity','priority', 'subject', 'status','created',get_description.short_description']

admin.site.register(DieTask, DieTaskAdmin)
```

i.e original text of description field contains more than 255 char.
I like to only display the first 10 char plus ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to create a property in the model as shown here:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars
...

@property
    def short_description(self):
        return truncatechars(self.description, 35)
```

And use the `short_descriptioin` in the admin to trim the text.

Answer (score 5):

how about using python inbuilt slice syntax

```
class DieTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =['severity','priority', 'subject', 'status','created','get_description']
    def get_description(self, obj):
        return obj.description[:10]
    get_description.short_description = "description"

admin.site.register(DieTask, DieTaskAdmin)
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I would also let anyone know who uses this that .short_description is the actual field here to put as the column head so that your column now doesn't just show as 'get_description'.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would avoid using Django template functions inside model methods/properties. IMO is cleaner solution use native Python method instead:

```
@property
def short_description(self):
    return self.description if len(self.description) < 35 else (self.description[:33] + '..')
```